# Html 5 canvas update with KinetickJS

Tags: html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am using KinetickJS to draw images on screen.
I have a layer on the stage, and recieve 1000 of images in base64 format.
First I try to draw them with Kinetic

Example 1, works fine BUT after 1000 of images when I try to drag or do something with layer it became veeeeeeeery slow.So I try next example

```
var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function () {
            var image = new Kinetic.Image({
                x: imageInfo.LocationX,
                y: imageInfo.LocationY,
                image: imageObj,
                width: imageInfo.Width,
                height: imageInfo.Height,
                name: "Update"
            });

            layer.add(image);
            layer.draw();

        };
        imageObj.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageInfo.Image;
```

Example 2, but in this case canvas began blinking for each update

```
var imageObj = new Image();


       imageObj.onload = function () {

                 var canvas = layer.canvas;
                  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//                   context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
             context.drawImage(imageObj, imageInfo.LocationX, imageInfo.LocationY);


            };
        imageObj.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageInfo.Image;
```

So do you have any ideas how to make it faster and/or disable blinking?

Comment: Forget to add, maybe its posible to combine or merger images or layers with kinetick. Because I do not need any action with images that come to me I just need to place it to correct position and scale.In this case I will have only one image on layer. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The newest KineticJS 4.3 speeds up dragging and other functionality quite a lot. This would probably fix your problem.

```
 http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.3.0.min.js
```